# How to create dynamic procedure where columns data is fetched from one table to another table using some sql function in some columns?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I created one stored procedure but I want to convert into a dynamic procedure.
How can I do this?
I tried to convert this procedure dynamically & its compiled too.
Please tell me, I transformed the pro

```
Compiled 

Connecting to the database cpRACTICE.
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database cpRACTICE.

SEVERE  168 0   oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$1    Index: -1, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:665)
/
Connecting to the database cpRACTICE.
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database cpRACTICE.

create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_TRNS_SRC_TRGT IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DM_TGT (
STUDY,
PATIENT,
CPEVENT,
SEX,
COUNTRY,
NAME,
AGE,
ADDRESS,
EPOCH,
--VISITNUMBER,
VISIT_DATE
)
(SELECT
STUDY,
PATIENT,
CPEVENT,
--SEX,
CASE WHEN SEX IN('M')
THEN 'MALE'
WHEN SEX IN('F')
THEN 'FEMALE'
WHEN SEX IN('O')
THEN 'OTHERS' END AS SEX,
SUBSTR(COUNTRY,1,3),
concat(concat(FIRST_NAME ,'_'),LAST_NAME),
AGE,
concat(concat(ADDRESS1,'/'),ADDRESS2),
EPOCH,
--TO_NUMBER(VISITNUMBER),
VISIT_DATE
            FROM
            DM_SRC 
            --where REGEXP_LIKE(VISITNUMBER,'[0-9])'
            );
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('procedure is unsuccessful' || sqlerrm);
END PRC_TRNS_SRC_TRGT;
```

I want this first stored procedure dynamically.
How can we do this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want it to be dynamic? What parameters of the query are going to be dynamic? Without a good reason, it is preferable to avoid dynamic SQL

Comment: I have to fetch data from the client's table to our source table. So, in that case, I don't know the table name & even column name too. For that, I want to write a dynamic procedure.